# Requesting a check in my understanding of Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have been learning Objective-C as my first language and understand Classes, Objects, instances, methods, OOP in general, etc enough to use the language and make simple applications work, but I wanted to check on a few fundamental questions that have never been explained in examples I followed.

I think the questions are so simple that they will confuse a lot of people, but I hope it will make sense to someone out there.

(While learning Objective-C the authors are assuming I have a basic computer programming background, yet I have found that a basic computer programming background is hard to come by since everyone teaching computer programming assumes you already have one to start teaching you something else. Hence the help with the fundamentals)

Passing and Returning:

When declaring methods with parameters how is the parameter stuff actually working if the arguments being passed into the parameters can have different names then the parameter names? I hope that makes sense. I know parameter names are variables for that very reason, but...
are the arguments themselves getting mapped to a look up table or something?

Second the argument "types" (int for example) have to match the parameter return types in order for them to be passed into the method, and you always have to make your arguments values equal the parameter names somewhere else in your code listing before passing them into the method?

Is the following correct: After a method gets executed it returns a particular value (if it is not void) to the class or instances that is calling the method in the first place.

Is object oriented programming really just passing "your" Objects instance methods around with the system generated classes and methods to produce a result?  If we are passing things to methods so they can do some work to them and then return something back why not do the work in the first place eliminating the need to pass anything? Theoretical question I guess? I assume the answer would be: Because that would be a crazy big tangled mess of a method with everything happening all at once, but I wanted to ask anyway.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Variables are just places where values are stored. When you pass a variable as an argument, you aren't actually passing the variable itself — you're passing the *value* of the variable, which is copied into the argument. There's no mapping table or anything — it just takes the value of the variable and sticks it in the argument.
   In the case of objects, the variable is a *pointer* to an object that exists somewhere in the program's memory space. In this case, the value of the pointer is copied just like any other variable, but it still points to the same object.
2. *(the argument "types" … have to match the parameter return types…)* It isn't technically true that the types have to be the same, though they usually should be. Some types can be automatically converted to another type. For example, a `char` or `short` will be promoted to an `int` if you pass them to a function or method that takes an `int`. There's a complicated set of rules around type conversions. One thing you usually should not do is use casts to shut up compiler warnings about incompatible types — the compiler takes that to mean, "It's OK, I know what I'm doing," even if you **really don't**. Also, object types cannot ever be converted this way, since the variables are just pointers and the objects themselves live somewhere else. If you assign the value of an `NSString*`variable to an `NSArray*` variable, you're just lying to the compiler about what the pointer is pointing to, not turning the string into an array.
3. Non-`void` functions and methods return a value to the place where they're called, yes.
4. *(Is object-oriented programming…)* Object-oriented programming is a way of structuring your program so that it can be conceptually described as a collection of objects sending messages to each other and doing things in response to those messages.
5. *(why not do the work in the first place eliminating the need to pass anything)* The primary problem in computer programming is writing code that humans can understand and improve later. Functions and methods allow us to break our code into manageable chunks that we can reason about. They also allow us to write code once and reuse it all over the place. If we didn't factor repeated code into functions, then we'd have to repeat the code every time it is needed, which both makes the program code much longer and introduces thousands of new opportunities for bugs to creep in. 50,000-line programs would become 500 million-line programs. Not only would the program be horrendously bug-ridden, but it would be such a huge ball of spaghetti that finding the bugs would be a Herculean task.

By the way, I think you might like Uli Kusterer's [Masters of the Void](http://masters-of-the-void.com/). It's a programming tutorial for Mac users who don't know anything about programming.

Comment: Thanks to all for clearing up the wonder of what is going on!

Answer (score 2):

"If we are passing things to methods so they can do some work to them and then return something back why not do the work in the first place eliminating the need to pass anything?"

In the beginning, that's how it was done.

But then smart programers noticed that they were repeating copies of some work and also running out of memory, so they decided to put that chunk of work in one central place to save memory, and then call it by passing in the data from where it was before.

They gave the locations, where the data was stuffed, names, because the programs were big enough that nobody memorized all the numerical address for every bit of data any more.

Then really really big computers finally got more 16k of memory, and the programs started to become big unmanageable messes, so they codified the practice as part of structured programming.  It's now a religious tenet.

But it's still done, by compilers when the inline flag is set, and also sometimes by hand on code that has to be really really fast on some very constrained processors by programmers who know when and where to make targeted trade-offs.

A little reading on the History of Computers is quite informative about how we got to where we are today, and why we do such strange things.

Comment: Yes I was reading about this today after I wrote this post. Thanks a bunch man.

Answer (score 0):

All that type checks used (at most) only during compilation stage, to fix errors in code.
Actually, during execution, all variables are just a block of memory, which is sent somewhere. For example, 'id' type and 'int' are both represented as 4-byte raw value, and you can write (int)id and (id)int to convert those type one to another.

And, about parameters names - they are used by compiler only to let it know, to which memory area send some data.

That's easy explanation, actually all that stuff is complicated, but I think you'll get the main idea - during execution there are no variable names/types, everything is done via operations over memory blocks.